# Making SpringBoot to use beans.xml

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans

Is it possible to make Spring boot use my Beans.xml file?
How can I supply context to it?
Is there any other way to put it?

Sincerely,
Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely! Just add a @Configuration with a @ImportResource. For more info, see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html